# Populate a string array from list array in Java

Tags: java, android, arrays

This is my first foray into Java, so forgive me if this is simple, but I am having difficulty iterating through a list and populating a string array with the list items.

Specifically, I am using Jsoup to parse a url and extract certain elements:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(content).get();
Elements threads = doc.getElementsByClass("page-link");
for (Element src : threads){
    String title = src.text();
    String href = src.attr("href");
        THREADS[0] = title;
}
```

THREADS is a string array:

```
static final String[] THREADS = new String[] {};
```

I don't seem to be able to iterate through the Elements array and populate THREADS with the title values.  Leaving the `THREADS[0]` index in the above example, successfully pushes the final title value into the string[], as expected.  But using a `for(i=0;i<25;i++)` type of loop around the `THREADS[i] = title;` statement causes a force close in the Android application.

Any tips would be awesome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've created a zero-element array, and arrays are not resizable. Is there any particular reason that you're not just using a `List<String>`?

```
static final List<String> THREADS = new ArrayList<String>();

// ...

for (Element src : threads){
    String title = src.text();
    String href = src.attr("href");
        THREADS.add(title);
}
```

Comment: possibly finishing with THREADS.toArray(new String[0]) to make an array at the end. If you *really* need an array.

Comment: Thanks, this works.  However, every time I call "static final List<String> THREADS = new ArrayList<String>();" it's not re-initializing as an empty list, and so THREADS.add() pushes into the previously created List.  I know this is probably better served as a different question, but my unfamiliarity with Java leaves me wondering if there is a simple method to ensure that THREADS is a initialized as an empty list every time it is called?

Comment: @aperture: every time what is called? Do you understand what `static` does?

Comment: The Jsoup.connect().get(); is called from a java class which receives its URL variable from an onclick event in another class. So, ideally, every time the onclick event is fired, THREADS gets populated with the new Elements.  What it's doing now is appending the new Elements on to the end of the previously called set. I am reading some documentation on static and final and what each implies and looking for what to change to achieve the desired result -- apparently, simply removing "static" was enough.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have to initialize your array:

```
static final String[] THREADS = new String[25];
```

Sure you don't actually mean `for(i=0;i>25;i++)` but desire `for(i=0;i<25;i++)`, see the differences in `<` `>`.

Or even better, as @Matt Ball suggested use a `List<String>`.

Answer (score 2):

The size of Java arrays is fixed on creation: they do not grow automatically when you add elements in them.

If you know beforehand the number of elements you will put into it, you can create the array with that size. In your case, something like:

```
String[] THREADS = new String[threads.size()];
int i = 0;
for (Element src : threads) {
  String title = src.text();
  String href = src.attr("href");
  THREADS[i++] = title;
}
```

Using arrays is not very idiomatic in Java however, as they are not very flexible (they have other issues with typing). It is more common to use one of the many collection types from `java.util`. The `List` interface and its `ArrayList` implementation provide the "growable array of elements" that you want:

```
List<String> THREADS = new ArrayList<String>();
for (Element src : threads) {
  String title = src.text();
  String href = src.attr("href");
  THREADS.add(title);
}
```